# Exporting values from multiple documents into Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, export, spreadsheet, lotusscript

How can I gather the information for each person, store it, get the information for the next person, store it and then place all of the information on the spreadsheet?

```vb
Sub Initialize

Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim lspTrainingDb As NotesDatabase

Dim view As NotesView
Dim uiView As NotesUIView
Dim childView As NotesView
Dim trainView As NotesView

Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim uiDoc As NotesUIDocument
Dim childDoc As NotesDocument
Dim trainDoc As NotesDocument

Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim dcTrain As NotesDocumentCollection

Dim TotalDocs As Long

Dim awards(24) As Variant
Dim commendations(74) As Variant
Dim xlArray() As String

Dim experience1 As Variant
Dim timeInGrade1 As Variant
Dim fullName As Variant
Dim allAwards As String
Dim allCommendations As String
Dim allTraining As String
Dim docKey As Variant
Dim vRecertify As Variant


Set db = s.CurrentDatabase


arrayDocs% = 0

Set uiView = ws.currentview
Set dc = uiView.documents

If(dc.Count = 0) Then
    MessageBox "Please select an officer. (To select a document, place a check mark in the column preceding the document)",48,"Error:"
    Exit Sub
End If



'Get field values from the LSP Training Records database
Set profileDoc = db.GetProfileDocument("ProfileDocument")
LSPTrainingServer$ = profileDoc.GetItemValue("LSPTrainingDbServer")(0)
LSPTrainingDbName$ = profileDoc.GetItemValue("LSPTrainingDbName")(0)


Set lspTrainingDb = New NotesDatabase(LSPTrainingServer$, LSPTrainingDbName$)   
Set trainView = lspTrainingDb.GetView("(DataNoSpreadsheetView)")



'   Set view = db.GetView("All Docs By Name")
Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument

While Not(doc Is Nothing)

    docKey = doc.GetItemValue("datanum")
    experience1 = doc.GetItemValue("HireDate")
    texperience1 = CStr(experience1(0))
    timeInGrade1 = doc.GetItemValue("RankDate")
    timeInGrade1 = CStr(timeInGrade1(0))
    fullName = doc.GetItemValue("FullName")
    tfullName = CStr(fullName(0))
    physicalCity = doc.GetItemValue("PhysicalCity")
    tPhysicalCity = CStr(physicalCity(0))


    Set children = doc.Responses            
    Set childDoc = children.GetFirstDocument

    Do Until childDoc Is Nothing

        If childDoc.Form(0) = "Awards" Then
            'Award Year fields
            awardYear1 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_1")
            tawardYear1 = CStr(awardYear1(0))
            awardYear2 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_2")
            tawardYear2 = CStr(awardYear2(0))
            awardYear3 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_3")
            tawardYear3 = CStr(awardYear3(0))
            awardYear4 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_4")
            tawardYear4 = CStr(awardYear4(0))
            awardYear5 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_5")
            tawardYear5 = CStr(awardYear5(0))
            awardYear6 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_6")
            tawardYear6 = CStr(awardYear6(0))
            awardYear7 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_7")
            tawardYear7 = CStr(awardYear7(0))
            awardYear8 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_8")
            tawardYear8 = CStr(awardYear8(0))
            awardYear9 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_9")
            tawardYear9 = CStr(awardYear9(0))
            awardYear10 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_10")
            tawardYear10 = CStr(awardYear10(0))
            awardYear11 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_11")
            tawardYear11 = CStr(awardYear11(0))
            awardYear12 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_12")
            tawardYear12 = CStr(awardYear12(0))
            awardYear13 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_13")
            tawardYear13 = CStr(awardYear13(0))
            awardYear14 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_14")
            tawardYear14 = CStr(awardYear14(0))
            awardYear15 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_15")
            tawardYear15 = CStr(awardYear15(0))
            awardYear16 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_16")
            tawardYear16 = CStr(awardYear16(0))
            awardYear17 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_17")
            tawardYear17 = CStr(awardYear17(0))
            awardYear18 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_18")
            tawardYear18 = CStr(awardYear18(0))
            awardYear19 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_19")
            tawardYear19 = CStr(awardYear19(0))
            awardYear20 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_20")
            tawardYear20 = CStr(awardYear20(0))
            awardYear21 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_21")
            tawardYear21 = CStr(awardYear21(0))
            awardYear22 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_22")
            tawardYear22 = CStr(awardYear22(0))
            awardYear23 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_23")
            tawardYear23 = CStr(awardYear23(0))
            awardYear24 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_24")
            tawardYear24 = CStr(awardYear24(0))
            awardYear25 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_25")
            tawardYear25 = CStr(awardYear25(0))

            'Award Type fields
            awardType1 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_1")
            tawardType1 = CStr(awardType1(0))
            awardType2 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_2")
            tawardType2 = CStr(awardType2(0))
            awardType3 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_3")
            tawardType3 = CStr(awardType3(0))
            awardType4 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_4")
            tawardType4 = CStr(awardType4(0))
            awardType5 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_5")
            tawardType5 = CStr(awardType5(0))
            awardType6 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_6")
            tawardType6 = CStr(awardType6(0))
            awardType7 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_7")
            tawardType7 = CStr(awardType7(0))
            awardType8 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_8")
            tawardType8 = CStr(awardType8(0))
            awardType9 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_9")
            tawardType9 = CStr(awardType9(0))
            awardType10 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_10")
            tawardType10 = CStr(awardType10(0))
            awardType11 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_11")
            tawardType11 = CStr(awardType11(0))
            awardType12 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_12")
            tawardType12 = CStr(awardType12(0))
            awardType13 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_13")
            tawardType13 = CStr(awardType13(0))
            awardType14 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_14")
            tawardType14 = CStr(awardType14(0))
            awardType15 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_15")
            tawardType15 = CStr(awardType15(0))
            awardType16 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_16")
            tawardType16 = CStr(awardType16(0))
            awardType17 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_17")
            tawardType17 = CStr(awardType17(0))
            awardType18 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_18")
            tawardType18 = CStr(awardType18(0))
            awardType19 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_19")
            tawardType19 = CStr(awardType19(0))
            awardType20 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_20")
            tawardType20 = CStr(awardType20(0))
            awardType21 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_21")
            tawardType21 = CStr(awardType21(0))
            awardType22 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_22")
            tawardType22 = CStr(awardType22(0))
            awardType23 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_23")
            tawardType23 = CStr(awardType23(0))
            awardType24 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_24")
            tawardType24 = CStr(awardType24(0))
            awardType25 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardType_25")
            tawardType25 = CStr(awardType25(0))

            allAwards = tawardType1 + " " + tawardYear1 + " " + tawardType2 + " " + tawardYear2 + " " + tawardType3 + " " + tawardYear3 + " " + _
            tawardType4 + " " + tawardYear4 + " " + tawardType5 + " " + tawardYear5 + " " + tawardType6 + " " + tawardYear6 + " " + _
            tawardType7 + " " + tawardYear7 + " " + tawardType8 + " " + tawardYear8 + " " + tawardType9 + " " + tawardYear9 + " " + _
            tawardType10 + " " + tawardYear10 + " " + tawardType11 + " " + tawardYear11 + " " + tawardType12 + " " + tawardYear12 + " " + _
            tawardType13 + " " + tawardYear13 + " " + tawardType14 + " " + tawardYear14 + " " + tawardType15 + " " + tawardType16 + " " + _
            tawardType17 + " " + tawardYear17 + " " + tawardType18 + " " + tawardYear18 + " " + tawardType19 + " " + tawardYear19 + " " + _
            tawardType20 + " " + tawardYear20 + " " + tawardType21 + " " + tawardYear21 + " " + tawardType22 + " " + tawardYear22 + " " + _
            tawardType23 + " " + tawardYear23 + " " + tawardType24 + " " + tawardYear24 + " " + tawardType25 + " " +tawardYear25
        End If



        If childDoc.Form(0) = "Disciplinary Actions" Then
            'Disciplinary Date Fields
            DiscDate1 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_1")
            tDiscDate1 = CStr(DiscDate1(0))
            DiscDate2 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_2")
            tDiscDate2 = CStr(DiscDate2(0))
            DiscDate3 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_3")
            tDiscDate3 = CStr(DiscDate3(0))
            DiscDate4 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_4")
            tDiscDate4 = CStr(DiscDate4(0))
            DiscDate5 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_5")
            tDiscDate5 = CStr(DiscDate5(0))
            DiscDate6 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_6")
            tDiscDate6 = CStr(DiscDate6(0))
            DiscDate7 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_7")
            tDiscDate7 = CStr(DiscDate7(0))
            DiscDate8 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_8")
            tDiscDate8 = CStr(DiscDate8(0))
            DiscDate9 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_9")
            tDiscDate9 = CStr(DiscDate9(0))
            DiscDate10 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_10")
            tDiscDate10 = CStr(DiscDate10(0))
            DiscDate11 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_11")
            tDiscDate11 = CStr(DiscDate11(0))
            DiscDate12 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_12")
            tDiscDate12 = CStr(DiscDate12(0))
            DiscDate13 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_13")
            tDiscDate13 = CStr(DiscDate13(0))
            DiscDate14 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_14")
            tDiscDate14 = CStr(DiscDate14(0))
            DiscDate15 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_15")
            tDiscDate15 = CStr(DiscDate15(0))
            DiscDate16 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_16")
            tDiscDate16 = CStr(DiscDate16(0))
            DiscDate17 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_17")
            tDiscDate17 = CStr(DiscDate17(0))
            DiscDate18 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_18")
            tDiscDate18 = CStr(DiscDate18(0))
            DiscDate19 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_19")
            tDiscDate19 = CStr(DiscDate19(0))
            DiscDate20 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_20")
            tDiscDate20 = CStr(DiscDate20(0))
            DiscDate21 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_21")
            tDiscDate21 = CStr(DiscDate21(0))
            DiscDate22 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_22")
            tDiscDate22 = CStr(DiscDate22(0))
            DiscDate23 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_23")
            tDiscDate23 = CStr(DiscDate23(0))
            DiscDate24 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_24")
            tDiscDate24 = CStr(DiscDate24(0))
            DiscDate25 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDate_25")
            tDiscDate25 = CStr(DiscDate25(0))

            'Disciplinary Charge Fields

            DiscCharge1 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_1")
            tDiscCharge1 = CStr(DiscCharge1(0))
            DiscCharge2 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_2")
            tDiscCharge2 = CStr(DiscCharge2(0))
            DiscCharge3 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_3")
            tDiscCharge3 = CStr(DiscCharge3(0))
            DiscCharge4 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_4")
            tDiscCharge4 = CStr(DiscCharge4(0))
            DiscCharge5 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_5")
            tDiscCharge5 = CStr(DiscCharge5(0))
            DiscCharge6 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_6")
            tDiscCharge6 = CStr(DiscCharge6(0))
            DiscCharge7 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_7")
            tDiscCharge7 = CStr(DiscCharge7(0))
            DiscCharge8 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_8")
            tDiscCharge8 = CStr(DiscCharge8(0))
            DiscCharge9 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_9")
            tDiscCharge9 = CStr(DiscCharge9(0))
            DiscCharge10 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_10")
            tDiscCharge10 = CStr(DiscCharge10(0))
            DiscCharge11 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_11")
            tDiscCharge11 = CStr(DiscCharge11(0))
            DiscCharge12 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_12")
            tDiscCharge12 = CStr(DiscCharge12(0))
            DiscCharge13 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_13")
            tDiscCharge13 = CStr(DiscCharge13(0))
            DiscCharge14 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_14")
            tDiscCharge14 = CStr(DiscCharge14(0))
            DiscCharge15 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_15")
            tDiscCharge15 = CStr(DiscCharge15(0))
            DiscCharge16 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_16")
            tDiscCharge16 = CStr(DiscCharge16(0))
            DiscCharge17 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_17")
            tDiscCharge17 = CStr(DiscCharge17(0))
            DiscCharge18 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_18")
            tDiscCharge18 = CStr(DiscCharge18(0))
            DiscCharge19 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_19")
            tDiscCharge19 = CStr(DiscCharge19(0))
            DiscCharge20 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_20")
            tDiscCharge20 = CStr(DiscCharge20(0))
            DiscCharge21 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_21")
            tDiscCharge21 = CStr(DiscCharge21(0))
            DiscCharge22 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_22")
            tDiscCharge22 = CStr(DiscCharge22(0))
            DiscCharge23 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_23")
            tDiscCharge23 = CStr(DiscCharge23(0))
            DiscCharge24 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_24")
            tDiscCharge24 = CStr(DiscCharge24(0))
            DiscCharge25 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscCharge_25")
            tDiscCharge25 = CStr(DiscCharge25(0))

            'Disciplinary Disposition Fields

            DiscDispo1 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_1")
            tDiscDispo1 = CStr(DiscDispo1(0))
            DiscDispo2 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_2")
            tDiscDispo2 = CStr(DiscDispo2(0))
            DiscDispo3 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_3")
            tDiscDispo3 = CStr(DiscDispo3(0))
            DiscDispo4 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_4")
            tDiscDispo4 = CStr(DiscDispo4(0))
            DiscDispo5 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_5")
            tDiscDispo5 = CStr(DiscDispo5(0))
            DiscDispo6 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_6")
            tDiscDispo6 = CStr(DiscDispo6(0))
            DiscDispo7 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_7")
            tDiscDispo7 = CStr(DiscDispo7(0))
            DiscDispo8 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_8")
            tDiscDispo8 = CStr(DiscDispo8(0))
            DiscDispo9 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_9")
            tDiscDispo9 = CStr(DiscDispo9(0))
            DiscDispo10 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_10")
            tDiscDispo10 = CStr(DiscDispo10(0))
            DiscDispo11 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_11")
            tDiscDispo11 = CStr(DiscDispo11(0))
            DiscDispo12 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_12")
            tDiscDispo12 = CStr(DiscDispo12(0))
            DiscDispo13 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_13")
            tDiscDispo13 = CStr(DiscDispo13(0))
            DiscDispo14 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_14")
            tDiscDispo14 = CStr(DiscDispo14(0))
            DiscDispo15 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_15")
            tDiscDispo15 = CStr(DiscDispo15(0))
            DiscDispo16 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_16")
            tDiscDispo16 = CStr(DiscDispo16(0))
            DiscDispo17 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_17")
            tDiscDispo17 = CStr(DiscDispo17(0))
            DiscDispo18 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_18")
            tDiscDispo18 = CStr(DiscDispo18(0))
            DiscDispo19 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_19")
            tDiscDispo19 = CStr(DiscDispo19(0))
            DiscDispo20 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_20")
            tDiscDispo20 = CStr(DiscDispo20(0))
            DiscDispo21 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_21")
            tDiscDispo21 = CStr(DiscDispo21(0))
            DiscDispo22 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_22")
            tDiscDispo22 = CStr(DiscDispo22(0))
            DiscDispo23 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_23")
            tDiscDispo23 = CStr(DiscDispo23(0))
            DiscDispo24 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_24")
            tDiscDispo24 = CStr(DiscDispo24(0))
            DiscDispo25 = childDoc.GetItemValue("DiscDispo_25")
            tDiscDispo25 = CStr(DiscDispo25(0))

            allDisciplinary = tDiscDate1 + "-" + tDiscCharge1 + "-" + tDiscDispo1  + " " + tDiscDate2 + "-" + tDiscCharge2 + "-" + tDiscDispo2 + " " + _
            tDiscDate3 + "-" + tDiscCharge3 + "-" + tDiscDispo3 + " " + tDiscDate4 + "-" + tDiscCharge4 + "-" + tDiscDispo4 + " " + _
            tDiscDate5 + "-" + tDiscCharge5 + "-" + tDiscDispo5 + " " + tDiscDate6 + "-" + tDiscCharge6 + "-" + tDiscDispo6 + " " + _
            tDiscDate7 + "-" + tDiscCharge7 + "-" + tDiscDispo7 + " " + tDiscDate8 + "-" + tDiscCharge8 + "-" + tDiscDispo8 + " " + _
            tDiscDate9 + "-" + tDiscCharge9 + "-" + tDiscDispo9 + " " + _
            tDiscDate10 + "-" + tDiscCharge10 + "-" + tDiscDispo10 + " " + tDiscDate11 + "-" + tDiscCharge11 + "-" + tDiscDispo11 + " " + _
            tDiscDate12 + "-" + tDiscCharge12 + "-" + tDiscDispo12 + " " + tDiscDate13 + "-" + tDiscCharge13 + "-" + tDiscDispo13 + " " + _
            tDiscDate14 + "-" + tDiscCharge14 + "-" + tDiscDispo14 + " " + tDiscDate15 + "-" + tDiscCharge15 + "-" + tDiscDispo15 + " " + _
            tDiscDate16 + "-" + tDiscCharge16 + " " + tDiscDate17 + "-" + tDiscCharge17 + " " + tDiscDate18 + "-" + tDiscCharge18 + " " + _
            tDiscDate19 + "-" + tDiscCharge19 + "-" + tDiscDispo19 + " " + tDiscDate20 + "-" + tDiscCharge20 + "-" + tDiscDispo20 + " " + _
            tDiscDate21 + "-" + tDiscCharge21 + "-" + tDiscDispo21 + " " + tDiscDate22 + "-" + tDiscCharge22 + "-" + tDiscDispo22 + " " + _
            tDiscDate23 + "-" + tDiscCharge23 + "-" + tDiscDispo23 + " " + tDiscDate24 + "-" + tDiscCharge24 + "-" + tDiscDispo24 + " " + _
            tDiscDate25 + "-" + tDiscCharge25 + "-" + tDiscDispo25
        End If

        Set childDoc = children.GetNextDocument(childDoc)
    Loop



    'Goes and gets information from LSP Training
    Set dcTrain = trainView.GetAllDocumentsByKey(docKey, True)
    Set trainDoc = dcTrain.GetFirstDocument
'       Set trainDoc = dc.GetFirstDocument
    trainView.AutoUpdate = False

    Do While Not (trainDoc Is Nothing)
        If (trainDoc.Form(0) = "Training Record") Then

            sInstTrnOfcr = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstTrnOfcr")
            If (sInstTrnOfcr(0) = "X") Then
                tInstTrnOfcr = "Field Training Officer"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstDutyOfcr = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstDutyOfcr")
            If (sInstDutyOfcr(0) = "X") Then
                tInstDutyOfcr = "Duty Officer"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstTechAccInvest = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstTechAccInvest")
            If (sInstTechAccInvest(0) = "X") Then
                tInstTechAccInvest = "Crash Reconstructionist"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstAccInvest = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstAccInvest")
            If (sInstAccInvest(0) = "X") Then
                tInstAccInvest = "Crash Investigation Instructor"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstDefTact = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstDefTact")
            If (sInstDefTact(0) = "X") Then
                tInstDefTact = "Defensive Tactics Instructor"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstPR24 = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstPR24")
            If (sInstPR24(0) = "X") Then
                tInstPR24 = "PR-24 Instructor"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstSWAT = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstSWAT")
            If (sInstSWAT(0) = "X") Then
                tInstSWAT = "SWAT"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstGeneral = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstGeneral")
            If (sInstGeneral(0) = "X") Then
                tInstGeneral = "General Instructor"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstRangeSafetyOfcr = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstRangeSafetyOfcr")
            If (sInstRangeSafetyOfcr(0) = "X") Then
                tInstRangeSafetyOfcr = "Range Safety Officer"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstFireArms = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstFireArms")
            If (sInstFireArms(0) = "X") Then
                tInstFireArms = "Firearms Instructor"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstTaser = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstTaser")
            If (sInstTaser(0) = "X") Then
                tInstTaser = "Taser Instructor"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstRadar = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstRadar")
            If (sInstRadar(0) = "X") Then
                tInstRadar = "RADAR/LIDAR Instructor"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstFirstAid = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstFirstAid")
            If (sInstFirstAid(0) = "X") Then
                tInstFirstAid = "First Aid Instructor"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstCPR = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstCPR")
            If (sInstCPR(0) = "X") Then
                tInstCPR = "CPR Instructor"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstDefDriv = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstDefDriv")
            If (sInstDefDriv(0) = "X") Then
                tInstDefDriv = "EVO Instructor"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstMotorcycle = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstMotorcycle")
            If (sInstMotorcycle(0) = "X") Then
                tInstMotorcycle = "Motorcycle Instructor"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstChildRestraint = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstChildRestraint")
            If (sInstChildRestraint(0) = "X") Then
                tInstChildRestraint = "Child Restraint Instructor"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstFldSobr = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstFldSobr")
            If (sInstFldSobr(0) = "X") Then
                tInstFldSobr = "SFST Instructor"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstDrugRecExpert = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstDrugRecExpert")
            If (sInstDrugRecExpert(0) = "X") Then
                tInstDrugRecExpert = "Drug Recognition Expert"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstFbiInstDevlp = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstFbiInstDevlp")
            If (sInstFbiInstDevlp(0) = "X") Then
                tInstFbiInstDevlp = "FBI Instructor Development"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstFBI = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstFBI")
            If (sInstFBI(0) = "X") Then
                tInstFBI = "FBI National Academy"
            Else 
            End If

            sInstNorthwestern = trainDoc.GetItemValue("InstNorthwestern")
            If (sInstNorthwestern(0) = "X") Then
                tInstNorthwestern = "NU School Police Staff/Command"
            Else 
            End If


            allTraining = tInstTrnOfcr + ",      " + tInstDutyOfcr + ",       " + tInstTechAccInvest + ",      " + tInstAccInvest + ",        " + _
            tInstDefTact  + ",      " + tInstPR24 + ",      " + tInstSWAT + ",      " + tInstGeneral + ",     " + tInstRangeSafetyOfcr + ",      " + _
            tInstFireArms + ",      " + tInstTaser + ",      " + tInstRadar + ",      " + tInstFirstAid + ",      " + tInstCPR + ",      " + _
            tInstDefDriv + ",      " + tInstMotorcycle + " ,     " + tInstChildRestraint + ",      " + tInstFldSobr + ",      " + tInstDrugRecExpert + "      " +_
            tInstFbiInstDevlp + ",      " + tInstFBI + ",      " + tInstNorthwestern

        End If


        If (trainDoc.Form(0) = "Recertify Record") Then
            vRecertify = childDoc.GetItemValue("RecertifyRequalSelection")
            tRecertify = CStr(vRecertify(0))
        End If
        Set trainDoc = dcTrain.GetNextDocument(trainDoc)
    '   Set trainDoc = dc.GetNextDocument(trainDoc)
    Loop

    Set doc = dc.GetNextDocument(doc)
Wend

'\\\Create the Report document

End Sub
```

Comment: No code - no help !!! - we're no psychics

Comment: It's best to not comment at all if you don't know or are not willing to help.  If more information is needed I can provide it.  Thanks for the "no help" anyway.

Comment: My comment was there to show, that noone can help you without code... The error you described was simply not answerable without your code... I removed my downvote, as with the code now it can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your code (which you should post!) is working. I would suggest to add a counter for each Notes document you process, that will help you address the correct row in the spreadsheet.

I would also recommend that you learn about arrays. They are a very fundamental concept in all programming, and you pretty much have to understand it in order to be a programmer. I would also suggest that you look at lists in Lotusscript, that is a very powerful data type.

You may also want to take at this class that I posted a while back:
http://blog.texasswede.com/export-notes-view-to-excel-with-multi-value-fields/

It creates a CSV file, but it should be trivial for you to modify it to write straight to a spreadsheet in Excel. You even have a counter in that code to count the rows...

**Update after code was posted**

You really need to learn about arrays. That code is many times longer and more convuluted than it has to be. You also use multiple steps when one step would be sufficient.

For example:

```
awardYear1 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_1")
tawardYear1 = CStr(awardYear1(0))
awardYear2 = childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_2")
tawardYear2 = CStr(awardYear2(0))
etc...
```

First of all, you could write it as follows, to avoid using temporary variables:

```
awardYear1 = Cstr(childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_1")(0))
```

But when you have 25 identical fields (which you should not have, it seems like the design of the original form is really bad as well), use an array:

```
Dim awardYear(24) as String
For i = 0 to 24
    awardYear(i) = Cstr( childDoc.GetItemValue("AwardYear_" & i+1)(0) )
Next
```

Those few lines would replace 50 lines of your code to start with...
You could do that through out your code, and make it much smaller. 
You could also use an array of a custom data type.

```
Type OfficerData
    awardYear As Integer
    awardType As String
    discDate As NotesDateTime
    discCharge As String
    discDispo As String
End Type

Dim officer(24) as OfficerData
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
officer(1).awardYear = 2010
officer(1).awardType = "Pistol Champion"
```

Easy, huh? :-)

You should always use Option Declare. This forces you to declare any variables but also helps you, in that it will be much easier to find typos in variable names. It is a long-established best practice.

Comment: My apologies for not including the code.  I got the message that there were too many characters for me to post it.

Comment: You can't post code in comments, so you should edit your original post. Don't forget to format the code as such, to make it easie rto read.

Comment: Thank you for your help Karl-Henry.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: The design of the form IS bad.  It's one of those things that's inherited.  Thanks again guys.  I've learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show, that i WANT to help: All things, that Karl-Henry mentioned are True. But the real problem in your code is: You reassign the values for e.g. `allAwards` within the loop. As you run through all documents, the variable will only contain the content of the LAST document.

And here again Karl-Henry is true: You should use an array to store the values...

```
Dim allAwards() as String

....

Set children = doc.Responses
Redim allAwards(children.Count-1)
i = 0

....     

allAwards(i) = tawardType1 + " " + tawardYear1 + " " + tawardType2 + " " + tawardYear2 + " " + tawardType3 + " " + tawardYear3 + " " + _
        tawardType4 + " " + tawardYear4 + " " + tawardType5 + " " + tawardYear5 + " " + tawardType6 + " " + tawardYear6 + " " + _
        tawardType7 + " " + tawardYear7 + " " + tawardType8 + " " + tawardYear8 + " " + tawardType9 + " " + tawardYear9 + " " + _
        tawardType10 + " " + tawardYear10 + " " + tawardType11 + " " + tawardYear11 + " " + tawardType12 + " " + tawardYear12 + " " + _
        tawardType13 + " " + tawardYear13 + " " + tawardType14 + " " + tawardYear14 + " " + tawardType15 + " " + tawardType16 + " " + _
        tawardType17 + " " + tawardYear17 + " " + tawardType18 + " " + tawardYear18 + " " + tawardType19 + " " + tawardYear19 + " " + _
        tawardType20 + " " + tawardYear20 + " " + tawardType21 + " " + tawardYear21 + " " + tawardType22 + " " + tawardYear22 + " " + _
        tawardType23 + " " + tawardYear23 + " " + tawardType24 + " " + tawardYear24 + " " + tawardType25 + " " +tawardYear25
i = i + 1
```

Like that you have ALL values of ALL documents in your Variable allAwards and can later cycle through this array to write each value into the excel- file.